# MS Access set cascade-to-null constraint to existing table

Tags: sql, ms-access, relationship

Using a MS Acess 2007 database accessed by vb.net application
I have two existing table

```
Members
-------
ID     name     bandID
-----------------------
0      Pierre   1
1      Chart    3
2      John     3
3      Dave     2  

Bands
-----
ID     bandName
----------------
1      Band a
2      Band b
3      Band c
```

I want to add an cascade to null constraint to the relation between members.bandId and bands.ID

This is what I have

```
ALTER TABLE members ADD CONSTRAINT membresBands_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (bandID) REFERENCE Bands(ID) ON DELETE CASCADE SET NULL
```

But I get this error message:

> Syntax error in CONSTRAINT clause

From msdn I found

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
  (OrderId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  CustId INTEGER, 
  OrderNotes NCHAR VARYING (255), 
  CONSTRAINT FKOrdersCustId FOREIGN KEY (CustId) 
  REFERENCES Customers ON UPDATE SET NULL ON DELETE SET NULL
```

Is it possible to alter a table in MS Access to set relationship to cascade to null?

Thank you!

Comment: You are mixing your terms. `CASCADE` and `SET NULL` are distinct referential actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to wait eight hours to post this...

Using a visual basic module

```
'Define the bit value for the relation Attributes.
Public Const dbRelationCascadeNull As Long = &H2000

Public Function MakeRel()
    'Purpose: Create a Cascade-to-Null relation using DAO.
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rel As DAO.Relation
    Dim fld As DAO.Field

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    'Arguments for CreateRelation(): any unique name, primary table, related table, attributes.
    Set rel = db.CreateRelation("membre_bands", "bands", "membres", dbRelationCascadeNull)
    Set fld = rel.CreateField("ID")  'The field from the primary table.
    fld.ForeignName = "band"           'Matching field from the related table.
    rel.Fields.Append fld                    'Add the field to the relation's Fields collection.
    db.Relations.Append rel                  'Add the relation to the database.


    'Report and clean up.
    Debug.Print rel.Attributes
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

then call the  MakeRel function

function found on http://allenbrowne.com/ser-64.html

Answer (score 5):

You *can* create this kind of constraint in Access, but only through the Jet OLE DB Provider and ADO.  For example, with the database in Access, you could create the constraint by running the following VBA code:

```
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute "ALTER TABLE membres ADD CONSTRAINT membresBands_FK FOREIGN KEY (bandID) REFERENCES bands(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL"
```

Comment: I just fixed my problem using a vb module as demonstrated on [link](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-64.html). I will look up your suggestion.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but got the same error message. There is probably something wrong with my query.

Comment: Did you try the query I posted or did you try the one posted in your original message?  The reason I ask is that, in the the query posted in your original message, `REFERENCE` should be `REFERENCES`.  In any case, I'm glad you found a solution one way or another.

Comment: I tried your query using a visual basic module. After some thought, I'm not sure this actually uses the Jet OLE DB and ADO

Comment: "You *can* create this kind of constraint in Access, but only through the Jet OLE DB Provider and ADO" -- Not quite correct. Using Access XP or later, the Access UI may be put into ANSI-92 Query Mode to run the same SQL DLL. [This article](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-64.html) demonstrates how to achieve the same using DAO code.

Comment: `CurrentProject.Connection` does indeed expose an ADO Connection object and therefore uses the OLE DB provider.

Comment: Thanks, I worked well. but why Access does not provide this functionality through UI!?

Answer (score 0):

Options for cascading effects in various DBMS are:

`ON DELETE SET NULL`

`ON DELETE CASCADE`

`ON DELETE RESTRICT`

`ON DELETE NO ACTION`

I think MS-Access has the first two. So, it should be:

`ON DELETE SET NULL`

Comment: I tried:
ALTER TABLE membres ADD CONSTRAINT membresBands_FK
        FOREIGN KEY (band) REFERENCE bands(ID) ON DELETE SET NULL

And i got the same error message

Comment: Not surprisingly it also supports `ON DELETE NO ACTION` and is the default option -- it would be most odd to force users to choose between the first two :) p.s. "cascading effects" is misleading (arguably only one of them 'cascades'); the standard SQL term is 'referential triggered actions' (and `SET NULL` is an example of a 'referential action').

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is NO `Cascade to Null` in Access. Only `Cascade Delete` and `Cascade Update`.

Comment: **From msdn:**
Cascading actions can also be defined by using the Foreign Key Relationships dialog box:     

_[ ON DELETE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]_    

_[ ON UPDATE { NO ACTION | CASCADE | SET NULL | SET DEFAULT } ]_

Comment: +1, I saw Brian's reply and your comments. I had never found that !

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for Access](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/275561) say that it supports the following referential triggered actions:

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE SET NULL
ON UPDATE SET NULL
```

...However, in practice it only supports the first three i.e. does not support `ON UPDATE SET NULL`. To further clarify, the engine does not support the `ON UPDATE SET NULL` referential triggered action at all i.e. not just the DDL syntax.