# Set default or set null for foreign key in MS access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am unable to set default or null value in MS access. For example, when I tried to delete parent row, the foreign key of the affected child row is not set to NULL. I have tried setting default value to NULL at the design view but it does not seem to work.

Here is my sample data: 
In staff table: 
`ID | Name` 
`1  | Tom`  
`2  | Tim`

In customer table: 
`ID | Name  | processed_By` 
`1  | cust1 | 2`

If I were to delete Tim from staff table, cust1 still retains 2 in `processed_By` column. However I wanted it to perform the following after deleting Tim from staff_table.

`ID | Name  | processed_By` 
`1  | cust1 | NULL`

OR

`ID | Name  | processed_By` 
`1  | cust1 | 1`

Hope that you can help me to solve this question. Thank you.

Comment: Please add more detail, for example, sample data and / or the code that did not work for you.

Comment: Hi Remou, I had updated it with sample data. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily enough in MS Access 2010 with the new [data macros](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)

Data macros even work when the table is used outside of MS Access. Note the keyword `Old`, applied to the Staff table where the After Delete macro is created. The line `/* delete` is a comment and purely for illustration.

[image: delete data macro]

Answer (score 2):

My impression is you were looking for `ON DELETE SET NULL`.  Access has supported that relationship feature since Jet 4 (Access 2000).  However, there is no provision in the Access user interface to set `ON DELETE SET NULL`.  You must do it from VBA code or with a DDL statement executed in SQL-92 mode.

I executed a DDL statement in the Immediate window.  Note `CurrentProject.Connection.Execute` is an ADO method, which means the query is executed in SQL-92 mode instead of Access' default SQL-89 mode.

```vba
strSql = "ALTER TABLE Customer" & vbCrLf & _
    "ADD CONSTRAINT processed_By_FK" & vbCrLf & _
    "FOREIGN KEY (processed_By) REFERENCES staff(ID)" & vbCrLf & _
    "ON DELETE SET NULL"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```

Afterward, I deleted the `staff` record for *Tim*.  That deletion caused the `Customer.processed_By` value for *cust1* to change from 2 to Null.

If this approach sounds interesting, you can find further information from Allen Browne at [Cascade to Null Relations](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-64.html) and from this Stack Overflow question: [MS Access set cascade-to-null constraint to existing table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386763/ms-access-set-cascade-to-null-constraint-to-existing-table).  There are several "*gotchas*" with `ON DELETE SET NULL`.

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be quite a reasonable feature. Do you know why they would keep this hidden from the user interface?

Comment: Not exactly, but I suspect it wasn't a deliberate choice to keep it hidden ... more likely they didn't see enough value to expose it in the UI.  I think this is similar to other Jet 4 features (check constraints as one example) which were never exposed in the UI.

Comment: If you test the example I provided, you may see this message when deleting *Tim* from the `staff` table: http://allenbrowne.com/graphics/CascadeDeleteDialog.gif  That doesn't seem right to me.  I said `ON DELETE SET NULL` is supported, but I didn't say it is supported well.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can do that. You can have the invalidated child row deleted automatically, but there is no built in function to set it back to null.

If your design really needs this, you can only do this through vba, but this only with a button on a form. When you delete rows directly in a table, I see no way to do this in access.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know that.